# Rebus Puzzles Everywhere!

Tags: rebus

Looking for a phrase in this puzzle :)

[image] [image]

Extra hint :

> Adjectives!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stretching a little (no indicator of the middle word), but is it

> **SILENT BUT DEADLY**, the most dangerous type of emission?

Comment: Yes Correct! I wanted to make the intended solution more difficult by not writing the middle word :)

Comment: I would argue that, since you didn't write the middle word, the intended solution is not the best fit. Other answers here, whilst they may not be the answers you were looking for, fit the puzzle better, precisely _because_ there is no middle word provided.

Comment: hmmm, I'll take note of that. Thx for the suggestion :) @bornfromanegg

Answer (score 3):

Could this be something along the lines of

> Dead quiet?

Comment: Nope. That's actually quite far :)

Comment: How about this, @KevinL?

Comment: Nope that's still incorrect :)

Answer (score 3):

Could be

> Toxic silence

since the second image

> looks like a poison symbol

Comment: unfortunately incorrect :)

Answer (score 2):

It must be

> Silence is deadly. Deadly because of the skull and silence because he has a zipper on his face which means he cannot speak

Or is it

> The Silent Dead

Comment: Still wrong mate :)

Comment: Edited! I will solve this one for sure :3

Comment: If u just change ur first answer a little, it's gonna be correct

Comment: So close yet so far!!

Comment: I wish I could accept ur first answer but the there's a little difference between yours and the intended solution :)

Comment: Haha. It's okay. I know I'm missing something very trivial here.

Comment: @KevinL how about now?

Comment: Hagfy's answer is the correct one. Sorry mate :)

Comment: XD whew. So close!!

Comment: I know right. If only u changed yours a little :)